# Excel chart: on/off values with timestamp

Tags: excel, charts

I have 3 columns of data, eg:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjGmu.jpg

When Excel creates a line graph of this, the blue line is what i get.

This is not correct because the time stamp shows the time when something is switched on (255) or off (0) (could also be the current state eg 16:08).  So I'd like a graph like this - see the red line (with a time-based X axis off course):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNvPk.jpg

Anyone can help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jon49 indicated, you need to plot additional data points--two y values for each x value: one to plot the point at y=255 and one to plot y=0.

If the time-span of the data is at least a few days, you can use a line chart. But in your case since the values are within a day, the scatter chart with straight lines is the only option due to the limitations of the scale units for line charts.

The key is the values need to be in the correct order. Each y=255 value needs to be followed by the next time-stamp's 255 value followed by it's 0 value, followed by the next time-stamp's 0 value:

[image]

Comment: Nice, this is the exact solution where I was looking for. Using the same principle, would it be possible to achieve the same thing using SSRS 2005?

Comment: In fact, the solution I used in Excel is this one: http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/charts/step_chart/  Is it possible to add error lines in SSRS 2005 so I could use the same solution?

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't support this type of discrete value graph (at least not excel 2k3 that I am using); your best bet is to use a bar graph and then go into the settings and set the gap width down to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the best way is but I would automate what I describe below on how to do (unless this is a one time deal, then just brute force it):

Separate the 255s from the 0s. Make sure for every 0 time there is a corresponding 255 time. Take the zero times and put in a scatter plot then add a y-error bar and make the fixed value equal to 255. Format to how you like it.

Now for the 255s. Add those to the chart by pairs. Make the chart type for these pairs scatter plot with a line. Format how you would like them to look.

Let me know if that doesn't make sense to you.